Populating TreeView from FTP directory in .NET Framework only after node is expanded
I have a server hosted in my Linux PC. Now I am creating a FTP client with some specific tools to handle. Now I want to generate my a TreeView in my windows form. I have already generated a treeview but it takes too much to login cause listing all the directories and sub directories take big amount of time when the directories increase. I want to load only the first layer of directories then when user clicks on the expand ('+') button then it should populate the directories under that and like it. How this can be done? My current treeview code look like this
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GISFileManagerClient
{
    public class TreeView
    {
        public FtpWebResponse PopulateDirectories(TreeNode parentNode,
            string ftpRootPath,
            string hostUsername,
            string hostPassword,
            FtpWebRequest request,
            FtpWebResponse response
            )
        {
            try
            {
                // ftp request for each directory list
                request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpRootPath);
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(hostUsername, hostPassword);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                request.KeepAlive = true;

                response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                string directoryContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string[] directories = directoryContents.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                List<string> modifiedDirectories = new List<string>();

                foreach (string directory in directories)
                {
                    // splitting directory name for refined folder
                    string[] parts = directory.Split('/');

                    // getting last string after '/' as that will be present directory "AWGSS/DG" will give DG
                    string modifiedDirectory = parts[parts.Length - 1];

                    // refined directories name to remove confusion
                    modifiedDirectories.Add(modifiedDirectory);
                }

                // converting list to string array before passing
                string[] finalDirectories = modifiedDirectories.ToArray();

                foreach (string directory in finalDirectories)
                {
                    // creating node for each directory
                    Console.WriteLine($"directory looks like this: {directory}");

                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(directory);
                    parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);

                    Console.WriteLine($"new stream looks like this: {ftpRootPath}/{Path.GetFileName(directory)}");
                    // condition to differentiate between file and directory
                    bool isDirectory = Path.GetFileName(directory).Contains(".");

                    if (isDirectory)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PopulateDirectories(node, $"{ftpRootPath}/{Path.GetFileName(directory)}", hostUsername, hostPassword, request, response);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
                // MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}



Tried to populate treeview directories frequently.
Expecting to populate subs on user clicking on expand button, not before.

Implement the TreeView.BeforeExpand event to populate the node only once the user expands it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeexpand
You will also have to make sure the expand button shows even for nodes that were not visited yet. While technically the underlying Windows Tree-view control does allow that (see TVIF_CHILDREN), this functionality does no seem to be exposed in WinForms. You will either have to implement that using P/Invoke (while it's doable, it's a lot of work, as the API is complex), or just add a fake child node to not-yet-populated nodes.
Related questions:

How can I show the plus and minus signs for nodes with children?
C# tree node show expand option even if node has no children


You should also consider populating the tree from a background thread, not to block the GUI thread. And that will actually allow you to populate whole tree on the background, not only once the user expands a node. But that's for another question.
